# On what principle does the universe run?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, time, universe

If we see the time period of the universe according to vedas , in the whole life span of Bramha consists of  almost **31346784 * 10<sup>14</sup>** human years.
It's like we are nothing in front of this unimaginable multiverse.

So the question is on what principle does all things happen?

Why Shri Hari Vishnu have to take avatar to kill Ravan , Kansh and all the evils,
why don't he just vanish them from the existence?
Why after a chatur yug next chatur yug comes , why after a day of Bramha everything is submerged and life starts again the following day.Since in the end everything have to be destroyed by the same mean then why everything is been created,  why everything is repeated again and again.

Comment: The answer to all your questions would be seen in Bhagavatham